# $A v = \lambda v \implies A^* v = \bar{\lambda} v$ if $A$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to show that if $A$ is normal then

$$ A v = \lambda v \implies A^* v = \bar{\lambda} v $$

I can show that $A^*v$ is also an eigenvector of $A$, using the fact that $A$ and $A^*$ commute, but I know that this *doesn*'t imply $A^* v \propto v$. So I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

**EDIT:** The top answer solves the problem, but I would like to know how to prove this result using *the polarisation identity* as suggested below. This is not the approach taken in the other questions on this site, linked to in the comments below.

Comment: $(\operatorname{span} \{v\})^\perp$ is $A$-invariant, i.e. $w\perp v \implies Aw \perp v$.

Comment: Actually that's what I'm trying to show using the above! How do you prove that?

Comment: On second thoughts, it is in fact easier the other way round.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/879787/, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/436318/

Answer (score 2):

For a normal operator $A$, we have $\lVert Aw\rVert = \lVert A^\ast w\rVert$ for all $w$. Now, assuming that $v$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we find

$$\langle A^\ast v, v\rangle = \langle v, Av\rangle = \langle v, \lambda v\rangle = \overline{\lambda}\langle v,v\rangle.\tag{1}$$

Further, we have

$$\lvert \langle A^\ast v, v\rangle\rvert \leqslant \lVert A^\ast v\rVert\cdot \lVert v\rVert = \lvert\lambda\rvert\cdot \lVert v\rVert^2\tag{2}$$

by the Cauchy-Bun'akovskij-Schwarz inequality. By $(1)$, we have the equality case, hence $A^\ast v$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, i.e. $A^\ast v = \mu\cdot v$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$. But then $(1)$ immediately yields $\mu = \overline{\lambda}$.

Comment: If we are using your first line, then we can note that $A-\lambda I$ is also normal, hence if $Av=\lambda v$ then $\|(A-\lambda I)^*v\|=\|(A-\lambda I) v\|=0$.

Comment: So true. That's better.

Answer (score 1):

Or you do what Daniel did $\langle A^\ast v, v\rangle = \langle v, Av\rangle = \langle v, \lambda v\rangle = \overline{\lambda}\langle v,v\rangle.\tag{1}$ and by polarization you have what you want.

Comment: What do you mean 'by polarisation'?

Comment: @gj255 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity this identity is very very useful!  You just show it for $<Ax,x>=...$ and you have it for $<Ax,y>=...$